# Dual Screen Win10 Setup, Mouse Gets Stuck Top Right Of Screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have 2 Dell U2415 screens setup via my Nvidia 970 card. One uses DVI other HDMI. Everything works perfectly, but since upgrading to Windows 10 there is one small issue.

When I put my cursor at the top right area of my 1st screen, and I want to move my mouse over to the 2nd screen, it gets stop there. There are like 5-10 pixels at the top which block it. If I move my cursor any lower, I can drag it to the other screen no problem.

This is the problem area:

[image]

I've checked my display settings, and both screens are aligned correctly:

[image]

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that they are aligned correctly? The preview is scaled, you probably wouldn't notice few pixels of offset. Try moving the screen a little bit. Also: since Windows 8.1 cursor sticks to screen edges when you move it slowly, try if it works if you move faster.

Comment: Pretty sure they are aligned perfectly yeah. When I line up a straight line between 2 screens, and drag my mouse, it follows it perfect. Doesn't jump up or down when it goes to the other screen. And going faster didn't make a difference.

Comment: Apparently its a feature, to make it easier to click the X top right of the first screen. Windows 7 didn't have this. I wish there was a regedit hack to remove this.

Comment: @Mr.Boon: Any reference as to how you know it's a feature? Do you maybe have a name for the feature, so that I can google for ways to disable it?